How to get Woocommerce Shop Page title?
I need to get the title of the shop page in WooCommerce. I mean the page: site.com/shop/
I've tried this:
global $post;

if ( class_exists( 'WooCommerce' ) && is_shop() ) :

  $post_type = get_post_type_object( get_post_type( $post ) );
  $title = $post_type -> labels -> name;

endif;

The variable $title will be used here:
<title><?php //custom title ?></title>
But it actually gives the name of the object while the name of the page is different.
Another solution is to make a header-shop.php file. But that won't work for me so far I make a custom function for all types of pages that will be used on other websites, too.
So, I just simply need to get the title of the shop page like I get the title of wordpress pages with the function get_the_title().

I have found the solution. The function get_the_title works fine for the shop page if it is used with the parameter get_option( 'woocommerce_shop_page_id' )
if ( class_exists( 'WooCommerce' ) && is_shop() ) :

  $title = get_the_title( get_option( 'woocommerce_shop_page_id' ) );

endif;

